# CSS: Undesired result from fixed positioning?

Tags: html, css

I've included the code I am using and example images to better explain what I want done

```
 <style>
            body {
                border: 5px double black;
                font-family: Courier;
                text-align:center;}
            .homepage {
                width: 75%;}
            .logo {    /*the image that you are seeing being sent behind the text*/
                width: 150px;
                }
            #header { /*the id of the div that is has the class="img" file nested*/
                display:block;
                margin:auto;
                border-bottom: 2px solid black
                }
            #intro {
                position:relative;}
            
        </style>
```

This is what I currently have, but want the `bottom-border` and everything above it to be under fixed positioning so when I scroll down it stays "glued" to the page.
[image: before]

and this is what I'm getting when I put `position:fixed;` in the `.logo` selector.

[image: after]

I've only been learning HTML/CSS for a few days and never fully understood whether to use `display`, and `position` in different situations and also in the Codecademy course I took also picked up the `z-index` tool. I don't know what the solution is to what I want to build.

Comment: Please provide your html code, too...

Answer (score 2):

Well, here we go on some explanation about each thing you asked (I believe that's better to you know what they do than just give you the code):

### position

It's for determining how your element will be positioned in the page. It plays together with `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` properties.
You have a few options here:

- `static`: The default behavior. The previously mentioned properties won't apply.
- `fixed`: Position the element relative to the screen viewport. It won't move when scrolling (your case!)
- `absolute`: Position the element relative to the closest positioned ancestor.
- `relative`: Lay out the element as it weren't positioned, and then adjust its position.

### z-index

It's for arranging your element in the 3rd dimension; for example, if 2 elements are overlaped, the one which haves the bigger `z-index` will be the topmost.

You need to position the element (set `position` to something else than `static`) to use `z-index`.

### display

You use `display` when you want to determine the render box of your element. The options are the following:

- `none`: the element will not be shown and will not occupy space on the screen.
- `inline`: the element generates one or more inline element boxes.
- `inline-block`: the element generate a block element box, but it'll stay in a single inline box.
- `block`: the element will generate a block element box.

You have also lots of other options, like `table`, `table-cell`, `table-cell-group`, `table-row`, `table-row-group`, `table-caption`, and others! As you imagina, each of these will behave as they corresponding table element.

I hope it helps you understanding these properties ;)
*Post created with infos from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/)*

Answer (score 1):

Here a basic example for how to set up a fixed header:

```
<div class="header">The header is here...</div>
<div class="main">The Main Story Is Here</div>
```

Start with two block level elements, one is fixed and the other contains the main content.

```
.header {
    border: 2px dotted gray;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(125,125,125,0.4);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.main {
    border-top: 2px solid red;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
```

Some key elements are: `top: 0` and `margin-top: 60px`

Your homework is to tweak those and figure out what they do.